# ios scoreboard/achievements for games

Tags: ios, gamekit, openfeint

I am planning to implement a global scoreboard and achievement system for my game(iOS). What is the best platform to do that ?

- GREE(formerly openfient)
- GameKit

Can someone tell me which one is better?(I just need a simple socreboard(like top 10 scores) and something that tracks achievements)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use GameKit / Game Center as personally I believe it provides a better experience for the end user.